# Error while Installing Packages from requirements.txt in python 3.9

Tags: python, django, requirements.txt

when i run `pip install -r requirements.txt` i get

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> cffi==1.14.0 (from versions: 0.1, 0.2, 0.2.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4.1, 0.4.2,
> 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.8, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.8.3, 0.8.4, 0.8.5,
> 0.8.6, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2.post2, 1.0.3, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2.0.post1, 1.2.1, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.10.0, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.11.4, 1.11.5, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.12.2, 1.12.3, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.14.3, 1.14.4, 1.14.5) ERROR: No matching distribution found for cffi==1.14.0

by the way my requirements.txt file contains

```
absl-py==0.9.0
asgiref==3.2.7
astor==0.8.0
astunparse==1.6.3
attrs==19.3.0
backcall==0.1.0
backoff==1.10.0
beautifulsoup4==4.9.1
bleach==3.1.4
blinker==1.4
bs4==0.0.1
cachetools==3.1.1
certifi==2020.4.5.1
cffi==1.14.0
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
cryptography==2.9.2
decorator==4.4.2
defusedxml==0.6.0
dill==0.3.1.1
Django==3.0.6
entrypoints==0.3
future==0.18.2
gast==0.3.3
geocoder==1.38.1
grpcio==1.27.2
h5py==2.10.0
idna==2.9
importlib-metadata==1.5.0
notebook==6.0.3
numpy==1.18.1
pickleshare==0.7.5
pyOpenSSL==19.1.0
pyrsistent==0.16.0
PySocks==1.7.1
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.1
pyzmq==18.1.1
qtconsole==4.7.4
QtPy==1.9.0
ratelim==0.1.6
requests==2.23.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
testpath==0.4.4
tornado==6.0.4
tqdm==4.46.0
traitlets==4.3.3
twilio==6.40.0
urllib3==1.25.8
widgetsnbextension==3.5.1
wrapt==1.12.1
zipp==3.1.0
bcrypt
argon2-cffi
django-allauth
pywhatkit
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the same issue (on Windows python `3.9.0`).

Turns out `cffi` (1.14.X) installs fine on python version `3.8.9` and none other than that.

Answer (score 3):

Pip decided that your system is not compatible. Please check if your Python version is compatible with the requirements of the module. You can get your Python version by executing `python --version`.

Comment: yeah , my python version is 3.9.1